# How to get the same amount of space before each arrow?

Tags: spacing, lists, indentation, itemize

I'm trying to reproduce a format of a list in latex and I can't find how to always have the same amount of space before each arrow even if there is some text. How to get automatically the same amount of space before "-> <Assign>" and before "-> <If>"?

[image: format of the list]

Answer (score 7):

You have several options. I use the following helper macro throughout this:

```
\newcommand\meta[1]{$\langle$#1$\rangle$}
```

We have to put `\relax` after `\\` if the following line starts with `[`, or else this is interpreted as the optional argument to `\\`.

### `tabular`

Perhaps the easiest.

```
\begin{tabular}{ll@{ $\rightarrow$ }l}
  [4] & \meta{Instruction} & \meta{Assign} \\\relax
  [5] &                    & \meta{If} \\\relax
  [6] &                    & \meta{While} \\\relax
  [7] &                    & \meta{Print} \\\relax
  [8] &                    & \meta{Read} \\\relax
  [9] & \meta{Assign}      & [VarName] := \meta{ExprArith}
\end{tabular}
```

### `tabbing`

Just because this is seldomly used.

```
\begin{tabbing}
  [4] \= \meta{Instruction} \= $\rightarrow$ \meta{Assign} \\\relax
  [5] \>                    \> $\rightarrow$ \meta{If} \\\relax
  [6] \>                    \> $\rightarrow$ \meta{While} \\\relax
  [7] \>                    \> $\rightarrow$ \meta{Print} \\\relax
  [8] \>                    \> $\rightarrow$ \meta{Read} \\\relax
  [9] \> \meta{Assign}      \> $\rightarrow$ [VarName] := \meta{ExprArith}
\end{tabbing}
```

---

Complete example showing `tabular` and `tabbing`:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{array}
\newcommand\meta[1]{$\langle$#1$\rangle$}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll@{ $\rightarrow$ }l}
  [4] & \meta{Instruction} & \meta{Assign} \\\relax
  [5] &                    & \meta{If} \\\relax
  [6] &                    & \meta{While} \\\relax
  [7] &                    & \meta{Print} \\\relax
  [8] &                    & \meta{Read} \\\relax
  [9] & \meta{Assign}      & [VarName] := \meta{ExprArith}
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabbing}
  [4] \= \meta{Instruction} \= $\rightarrow$ \meta{Assign} \\\relax
  [5] \>                    \> $\rightarrow$ \meta{If} \\\relax
  [6] \>                    \> $\rightarrow$ \meta{While} \\\relax
  [7] \>                    \> $\rightarrow$ \meta{Print} \\\relax
  [8] \>                    \> $\rightarrow$ \meta{Read} \\\relax
  [9] \> \meta{Assign}      \> $\rightarrow$ [VarName] := \meta{ExprArith}
\end{tabbing}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

---

### Other options

Instead of `tabular` you could use `longtable` to get something that is page breakable.

#### `description` environment with `enumitem`

This one is admittedly a bit of a hack, but one could also define a formatting macro and use a `description` list. The following defines `\myformatter` to format the start of each row. It takes two optional arguments, the first should be the widest entry of the second column, in this case `Instruction`, the second should be the widest number in the line numbering.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\newcommand\meta[1]{$\langle$#1$\rangle$}
\newcounter{mylinenumber}
\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand\myformatter { O{} O{0} m }
  {%
    [\phantom{#2}\llap{\arabic{mylinenumber}}]% right aligned, brackets outside
    %[\rlap{\arabic{mylinenumber}}\phantom{#2}]% left aligned, brackets outside
    %\phantom{[#2]}\llap{[\arabic{mylinenumber}]}% right aligned, brackets packed
    %\rlap{[\arabic{mylinenumber}]}\phantom{[#2]}% left aligned, brackets packed
    \hspace{1em}%
    \ifx\@itemlabel#3%
    \else
      \rlap{\meta{#3}}%
    \fi
    \phantom{\meta{#1}}%
    \hspace{.5em}$\rightarrow$\hspace{.5em}%
    \stepcounter{mylinenumber}%
    \ignorespaces
  }
\makeatother  

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{mylinenumber}{6}% number of the first row
\begin{description}[{format=\normalfont\myformatter[Instruction][10]}]
  \item[Instruction] \meta{Assign}
  \item \meta{If}
  \item \meta{While}
  \item \meta{Print}
  \item \meta{Read}
  \item[Assign] [VarName] := \meta{ExprArith}
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

There are different ways how you could align the brackets and line numbers, the one shown above is the one not commented out. Pick the version you like best by commenting out the others while keeping the one alignment you like (the comments after each line should hint at what this looks like).

---

### Adding the line numbers automatically in the `tabular` approach.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{array}
\newcommand\meta[1]{$\langle$#1$\rangle$}
\newcounter{mylinenumber}
\newcommand*\mylinenumber[1][0]
  {%
    [\phantom{#1}\llap{\arabic{mylinenumber}}]%
    \stepcounter{mylinenumber}%
  }

\begin{document}
\setcounter{mylinenumber}{4}% number of the first row
\begin{tabular}{>{\mylinenumber\hspace{1em}}l@{ $\rightarrow$ }l}
  \meta{Instruction} & \meta{Assign} \\\relax
                     & \meta{If} \\\relax
                     & \meta{While} \\\relax
                     & \meta{Print} \\\relax
                     & \meta{Read} \\\relax
  \meta{Assign}      & [VarName] := \meta{ExprArith}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Nice answer, but you might want to suppress the indentation before the `tabular` example with `\noindent`.  Also, you didn't consider what happens if the list numbers get to two digits (although that wasn't asked for).  (+1 anyhow.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton I did, just change the optional argument to `\mylinenumber` to the widest number, then the numbers will be right aligned inside the brackets.

Comment: @barbarabeeton and `\noindent` is of course an option, but since I don't know the final placement of this, I didn't use it. The `description` approach is missing that spacing for the widest entry, though, I'll edit.